# Is potential Difference Really a Measure of Electromotive force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

If I separate some amount of positive and negative charge a certain distance I will create some voltage. If I then separate the same amount of positive and negative charge a longer distance I will create an even bigger voltage since more work would've been needed to separate them.

Now, the charges with a larger potential difference will experience less of a force of attraction because they're farther apart, and the charges with a lower potential difference will experience a larger force of attraction since they are closer together.

Question 1: If voltage is a measure of the "push" acting on charge, then how can this be so?

Question 2: Voltage is proportional to current. But in this case I would think that the lower voltage scenario would produce higher current because there's a stronger force acting on the charge. What's going on? How does potential difference produce current?

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer an Old fashioned answer: Voltage is NOT  like push!  Voltage is more like pressure in a fluid, where now “pressure gradient” causes push. Electric fluid gets pushed from high pressure to low. So voltage gradient or volts per metre gives electric field or force per coulomb. Hope this helps too.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field is a measure of the "push" acting on an electric charge. The voltage (aka electrical potential) is a measure of the energy required to move an electric charge from one location to another location in an electric field. There is an analogy with gravity: the gravitational field at your location is a measure of the "pull" you feel. The gravitational potential is a measure of the energy required to move your body from the bottom of a ladder to the top of the ladder.